# How to enable Gift cards feature in magento like amazon?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I need to enable gift card option in magento without using any extension. The gift card feature should be like amazon's gift card.

Can anyone please tell me to enable this feature in magento?

Answer (score 0):

Below free giftcard extension you can use

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/devsters-gift-cards.html

Also you try below links

https://github.com/WarbyParker/Warby_BulkGiftAccount

https://github.com/merchantwarehouse/shopping-cart-integrations/tree/master/magento

Comment: Hi Arjun, I have tried the extension devsters-gift-card extension. I'm getting extension key error when I install using it..  http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Devsters_Gift_Cards I think it is compatible for magento version 2

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/kartparadigm-giftcard.html

Comment: I have used above extension too. getting same extension key error. They have mentioned that Compatible with: 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.9. But its not worked out..

Comment: https://www.evohosting.co.uk/blog/web-development/ecommerce-web-development/5-best-free-magento-extensions-gift-giving/

Comment: For devsters gift cart use this link https://github.com/5mehulhelp5/MagentoExtensions/tree/master/Devsters%20Gift%20Cards%20with%20some%20extra%20modification

Answer (score 0):

The GIftCard feature is only available on Magento Enterprise (EE). 
You have to use extension to get it on CE version.

Comment: Hi Walish, Thanks a lot... Can you please suggest me some extension? I have used 2 free plugins                                                                                    1. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/devsters-gift-cards.html                                                                                                             2. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/kartparadigm-giftcard.html?utm_campaign=bazaarvoice&utm_medium=Default&utm_source=RatingsAndReviews&utm_content=Default

Comment: The devsters gift card couldn't work but the second one works good. I have some issues in kartparadigm extension.  Pl look into the screenshot. http://imgur.com/NNckrvq. I couldn't change UI.

Comment: Oh, some extensions only compatible with default theme. You have to customize its template.